# Jquery/Ajax - Return custom alert if callback success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to use jquery / javascript to return my custom alert box for the returned ajax value is either 0 or 1. 1 being success or 0 being error.

Now i know this won't work as I tried it but I'm going to leave the functions in here so you can see what I'm trying to do more clearly.

```
<script>
$("#login_form").submit(function() {
    $('.social').hide('slow');
    if ($("#login_form").valid()) {

          $('.messagebox').slideUp('slow');
        var data1 = $('#login_form').serialize();
            $("button").button('loading');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "includes/login.php",
            data: data1,
                  dataType: 'json',
            success: function(msg) {

            if (msg.result == 1) {

              showSuccess();
              setTimeout("window.location.href='members.php';",4000);

            } else {
                      $("button").button('reset');
                      console.log(msg.result);

                showError();

                      }
            }
        });

    }
    return false;
});
</script>
```

Now as you can see, I want to automatically show a custom alert box stored in the separate functions for if the msg.result == 1 or 0. 
I don't want it on a click, I want it on a success and error callback.

My custom alert box is :

```
webpackJsonp([15], {
240: function(t, e) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        "use strict";

        $("#notification-success").on("click", function() {
            $.gritter.add({
                class_name: "-success",
                title: "Success Notification",
                text: "Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their model text.",
                time: 6e3
            })
        })

        $("#notification-danger").on("click", function() {
            $.gritter.add({
                class_name: "-danger",
                title: "Danger Notification",
                text: "Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their model text.",
                time: 6e3
            })
        })

        $("#notification-info").on("click", function() {
            $.gritter.add({
                class_name: "-info",
                title: "Info Notification",
                text: "Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their model text.",
                time: 6e3
            })
        })

        function showSuccess() {
            $.gritter.add({
                class_name: "-success",
                title: "Successful Login",
                text: "You have successfully logged in!<br>Redirecting you now.",
                time: 6e3
            })
        };

        function showError() {
            $.gritter.add({
                class_name: "-danger",
                title: "An error occured",
                text: "You have entered in the wrong credentials.",
                time: 6e3
            })
        };

    })
},
334: function(t, e, i) { i(240) }
}, [334]);
```

You see I have tried making some functions in this seperate file.
I call this file at the bottom of my other index.php page (the page where I am storing the code at the top of this page.

Comment: you need to make sure that the showError() and showSucess() fonctions are loaded before the first code ( form submit ).

Try to call the file in the header instead of the footer

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes Thanks for your fast reply but I just tried this and it says that the functions are not defined - (the showError and showSuccess)

Comment: ok good that means the order is correct so do you have any think in your console ( console.log(msg.result); ) ?

Comment: @seifeddineBesbes I should yes as It was working before, I just want to change the alert style.

Comment: ok so you'r using https://github.com/jboesch/Gritter to manage notifications can you just make the style changes in the css file and add the appropriate class to the $.gritter.add function ?

Comment: This `setTimeout("window.location.href='members.php';",4000);` will definitely not work, *setTimeout()* [needs a function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) as first argument. You can do this: `setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="members.php";},4000);`.

Comment: And I think your `showSuccess()` and `showError()` need to be declared in global namespace (outside the `document.ready` to be visible to the *submit* function. Either that, or the *submit* needs to be placed in the same `document.ready` as the two functions.